# Octave Error with XLS functions

Tags: java, windows, excel, io, octave

I just started using Octave, and have been trying to do some operations from data in Excel files.  I've installed the IO, Java, and Windows packages in Octave, but when I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
Looking for supported interfaces:
Excel/COM... not working.
error: No Java support found.
error: called from:
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\packages\io-1.0.14\xlsopen.m at
line 395, column 1
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\packages\io-1.0.14\xlsopen.m at
line 168, column 15
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\packages\io-1.0.14\xlsread.m at
line 215, column 1
error:   C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\nighttime2.m at line 30, column 18
```

I've been trying to solve this for a little while now so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first error is 
`No Java support found.`
So it's probably because you have not properly installed the java package.

Read and follow the instructions under the section **How to install the java package in Octave?** in the [documentation](http://wiki.octave.org/Java_package).

There is also a document called: [How to install the java package in Octave?](http://openjevis.org/attachments/download/380/How_to_install_the_java_package_in_Octave_20120924.pdf)  that can be helpful.